# Enzyme, find ID with swedish letters?

Tags: javascript, enzyme

I'm doing an expect:

```
expect(renderedComponent.find(`#åäö`).length).toBe(1);
```

I get an error saying:

> Failed to parse selector: #åäö

Is there a way to get Enzyme to recognize these characters?

Comment: why do you not use Unicode chars? ("#first❤♡❤")

Comment: @zemil I wish it was my decision. It's how the system is designed.

Comment: at first, try to watch  the in scripts in packag.json "test": "test jest --watch", and add the debug the renderedComponent before do any think as console.log(renderedComponent.debug()) check if that found or not

Comment: @Mohammed_Alreai It does get rendered in the .debug().

Comment: it shows the component wants to test is contain the id ="åäö"

Comment: @Mohammed_Alreai Yes and that component is shown in the .debug(). So it does exist with that ID.

Comment: at first do you eant take the value found in this id you shoud it("elemrnt found id ",()=>{
  expect(renderedComponent.find(`#åäö`).text().exits()).toEqual(true);
})

Comment: @Mohammed_Alreai It doesn't work either. The parse selector can't parse åäö at all.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199296/discussion-between-mohammed-alreai-and-lithicas).